# How to work around cdr not understanding the empty list?

Tags: scheme

My problem is the `butSecondLastAtom` algorithm. It doesn't work because cdr doesn't comprehend an empty list. But I see no other way of writing the algorithm. It's at the end of the page. Everything works but when the last element of a list is a list. 
http://lpaste.net/110959

The problem is in the recursive call of (cdr (cdr l)) but more in the 3rd condition. Idk what to do. I'm just going to stop tonight and start fresh in the morning.

```
((and (isAtom (second_last_element l)) (notAtom (last_element l)))
        (cons
           (car l)
             (butSecondLastAtom (last_element l))))
```

Comment: For a solution that doesn't flatten, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827250/deleting-second-last-atom/25828080#25828080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem in your code is the use of `null?` or `cdr` on the `cdr` of a list, both in `flatten` and in `butLast`. Don't do this; always use the procedures and predicates on the list itself.

I'd suggest the following:

**Flattening the list**

Most Schemes have a version of `flatten` build-in, which takes care of *nested lists* and *improper lists*. The version you implemented is not entirely correct (try `(flatten '())`), use this one:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
    (cond 
      ((null? lst) res)
      ((pair? lst) (loop (car lst) (loop (cdr lst) res)))
      (else        (cons lst res)))))

> (flatten '(1 2 (3 (4 5 6))))
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
> (flatten '(1 2 (3 (4 5 (6)))))
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
> (flatten '())
'()
```

**Dropping the second last element**

So this becomes much easier now, looping through a simple flat proper list while keeping track of the last (`n-1`) and second-last (`n-2`) element. An example implementation is:

```
(define (butSecondLastAtom lst)
  (define flst (flatten lst))
  (if (< (length flst) 2)
      flst
      (let loop ((flst (cddr flst)) (n-2 (car flst)) (n-1 (cadr flst)) (res null))
        (if (null? flst)
            (reverse (cons n-1 res)) ; here we drop the second-last element
            (loop (cdr flst) n-1 (car flst) (cons n-2 res))))))
```

If you want to avoid going through the list twice (once for `length`, once for the loop), you can also keep track of the length yourself:

```
(define (butSecondLastAtom lst)
  (define flst (flatten lst))
  (let loop ((lst flst) (len 0) (n-2 #f) (n-1 #f) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        (if (< len 2)
            flst
            (reverse (cons n-1 res))) ; here we drop the second-last element
        (loop (cdr lst) (add1 len) n-1 (car lst) (if (< len 2) null (cons n-2 res))))))
```

Testing

```
> (butSecondLastAtom '(1 2 (3 (4 5 6))))
'(1 2 3 4 6)
> (butSecondLastAtom '(1 2 (3 (4 5 (6)))))
'(1 2 3 4 6)
> (butSecondLastAtom '(((a))))
'(a)
> (butSecondLastAtom '())
'()
```

Comment: Premature optimization. Last time I timed that I found out that using `length` might even be marginally faster than not traversing a list twice.

Comment: @Sylwester That's my feeling too, but I haven't measured anything. I also find the first version more elegant. But there were times when inevitably somebody would have brought this up, so there ;-)