# Deleting Second last ATOM

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to delete second last ATOM from the given list -

```
(define (butSecondLastAtom lst1)
 (cond 
   ((null? lst1) '())
   ((null? (cdr lst1)) lst1)
   ((null? (cddr lst1))
   (cond((not(pair? (car lst1))) (cdr lst1))
     (else (cons(butLastAtom (car lst1)) (cdr lst1)))))
(else (cons (car lst1) (butSecondLastAtom(cdr lst1))))))

(define (butLastAtom x)
    (cond ((null? (cdr x))
      (cond ((not(pair? (car x))) '())
           (else (cons (butLastAtom(car x)) '()))))
    (else (cons (car x) (butLastAtom(cdr x))))))
```

This code do delete the second last atom but fails for following condition -
if input is like (a (b (c (d))))  then output should result in (a (b ((d)))).
Please update where i am being wrong or with a solution.

Comment: `(butSecondLastAtom '(1 2 (3 (4 5 (6)))))` yields `'(1 (3 (4 5 (6))))`. You actually delete the second atom, sometimes the first, but not the second last.

Comment: So how to delete Second last ? but this code take care of stuff like if the second last atom is list then delete the last atom of it. Like -(butSecondLastAtom '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6)) will give me as expected - (1 2 3 (4) 6)

Comment: So deletion occurs more or less at random with your code. There was an earlier question on this here, is the result supposed to be flattened or not?

Comment: No result should be same as input bt just removing the second last Atom , not flattening.

Comment: **"if the second last atom is list"** This doesn't make any sense. "Atom" is a technical term---it means anything that's not a pair.  A (non-empty) list is not an atom.

Comment: If second last element is a list then check within itself to delete last atom of second last list

Comment: @BeingCoder I understand the result that you *want*; my point it a list (except for the empty list) is *not* an atom, so it will never be the case that "the second last atom is a list".  I think you could use the term element (as in "the second to last element of the list").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that's basically copying a *tree*.  The trick to removing an element at a given position from the right is to decrement *n* each time we process a leaf.  The element that we want to remove must be the car of some pair, so the part of the copying routine that rebuilds a pair just needs to be able to watch for when that happens.  We can "signal" it by returning some special value instead of the *n*<sup>th</sup> item.  What special value can  we use?  We've already defined an internal function that nothing else will have access to, so we can use it.

```
(define (rem n tree)
  ;; Returns a new tree similar to the input, 
  ;; but without the nth leaf from the right.
  (let rem ((tree tree))
    (cond
      ;; Copy the empty tree by returning the empty tree.
      ((null? tree)
       '())
      ;; Copy a pair by copying the right and left subtrees, 
      ;; and then putting them back together.  The exception 
      ;; is when the car is the nth element (and the "copy" of 
      ;; it is the special value).  In that case, we just
      ;; return the copy of the right subtree.
      ((pair? tree)
       (let ((r (rem (cdr tree)))  ; copy the right subtree
             (l (rem (car tree)))) ; copy the left subtree
         (if (eq? l rem)
             r
             (cons l r))))
      ;; When we encounter a leaf, decrement the counter.  
      ;; If it's zero (which means we want to discard this leaf),
      ;; then return the special value.  Otherwise, return
      ;; the leaf.
      (else
       (set! n (- n 1))
       (if (= n 0) rem tree)))))
```

```
> (rem 2 '(a (b (c (d)))))
(a (b ((d))))
```

After that, it's easy to define your more specific version:

```
(define (butSecondLastAtom lst1)
  (rem 2 lst1))
```

```
> (butSecondLastAtom '(a b (c d) ((e f) (g))))
(a b (c d) ((e) (g)))
```

Comment: +1 Better than mine, produces the same results. Never seen somebody use a procedure as a flag ;-)

Comment: @uselpa In Common Lisp I'd usually use a gensym, but didn't know what was available in Scheme and Racket.  My first draft used a pair `(cons 1 1)`, but then it occurred to me that that might not be local to the procedure in Racket, with its immutable pairs.  (I.e., since their immutable, they it could be the same as any other `(cons 1 1)`.  The procedure is restricted to the scope though, so nothing else should be able to get at it.

Comment: Note that Racket has `(gensym)` as well, but this is cooler ;-)

Comment: Really nice solution , appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

The following works for my understanding of the problem, but since you provide only one testcase please make sure this is what you want.

The solution has 2 passes:

**pass 1 - count the number of atoms**

Fairly classical, count how many atoms we have so that we can compute which one to drop later on:

```
(define (count-atoms sexp)
  (cond
    ((null? sexp) 0)
    ((pair? sexp) (+ (count-atoms (car sexp)) (count-atoms (cdr sexp))))
    (else 1)))
```

**pass 2 - copy without the second last**

First, I need an `atom?` predicate here:

```
(define (atom? x) 
  (not (or (pair? x) (null? x))))
```

Copying *without* dropping any element is very similar to the previous function:

```
(define (copy sexp)
  (cond
    ((or (null? sexp) (atom? sexp)) sexp)
    (else (cons (copy (car sexp)) (copy (cdr sexp))))))
```

In order to drop an element, we need to change the second clause, and introduce a counter so that we know when we meet the element to drop:

```
(define (butSecondLastAtom sexp)
  (define n 1)                       ; counter of atoms
  (define ignore (count-atoms sexp)) ; index of element to ignore
  (define (sub sexp)                 ; the copy subroutine
    (cond
      ((null? sexp) null)
      ((atom? sexp)
       (set! n (add1 n))               ; increase n
       sexp)
      (else 
       (let* ((left   (sub (car sexp))) ; process car of cons cell
              (leftn  n)                ; keep track of n after processing car
              (right  (sub (cdr sexp))) ; process cdr of cons cell
              (rightn n))              ; keep track of n after processing cdr
         (cond
           ((and (atom? left)  (= leftn  ignore)) right)
           ((and (atom? right) (= rightn ignore)) left)
           (else (cons left right)))))))
  (sub sexp))
```

Here are my test cases:

```
(require rackunit)

(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom null) null)
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom 1) 1)
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a b))  '(b))
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a . b)) 'b)
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a (b . c))) '(a c))
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(1 2 (3 (4 5 (6 . 7))))) '(1 2 (3 (4 5 7))))
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a (b (c) d))) '(a (b () d)))
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a (c d) e)) '(a (c) e))
(check-equal? (butSecondLastAtom '(a (b (c (d))))) '(a (b ((d)))))
```

Comment: Another approach might to be copy the list, but from the "end" (which presents its own challenges) and ignoring the "second" leaf encountered.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I thought about that, but that would need 2 `deep-reverse`s (not fast) and otherwise the code would be exactly the same; only the index of the position to ignore would be different.

Comment: When I considered the idea, I thought about doing, in essence, tree mapping, but touching the cdr before the car, and mapping a function with some mutable state that would doing something special the second time it was called (return a sentinel or something).

Comment: Hold on, there's one test case for which it doesn't work: `'(a (c d) e))`

Comment: But as i mentioned in my question , this code is not preserving parenthesis. example - testcase -  
input - (a (b (c (d)))) 
output - (a (b ((d))))

Comment: OK, modified for the test case. The procedure does preserve parentheses, see my last test case.

Comment: @uselpa Acutally, I implemented the idea I was talking about in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25828316/1281433), and while it does copy the list, it only requires one pass though, and it's not all that complicated.